# Android checkbox with custom selector inside recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I made recyclerview with checkbox so you can select each item and button on bottom of the screen when pressed return selected items from list.The problem is that no matter what i do button always return that 0 items were selected.I found that checkbox status is always false even thought icon from checkbox change when i click checkbox. I use custom selector to change icon inside checkbox but i can't find the way to change checkbox status inside program.

This is the fragment that contain recyclerview

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Resources res = getResources();
    titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.muscle_titles);

    recyclerMain = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MainList);
    adapter = new MainAdapter(getActivity(), getData(getActivity()));
    recyclerMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return rootView;
}

public static List<MainRowInformation> getData(Context context){
    List<MainRowInformation> data = new ArrayList<>();


    for(int i=0;i<titles.length;i++){

        final MainRowInformation current = new MainRowInformation();
        current.title = titles[i];
        current.checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
        current.checkBox.setChecked(false);


        data.add(current);
    }

    return data;
}
```

This is recyclerview adapter

```
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<MainRowInformation> data = Collections.emptyList();

public MainAdapter(Context context, List<MainRowInformation> data) {
    this.data = data;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_main, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MainRowInformation current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    //mozda je krivo sljedeca linija
    holder.checkbox = current.checkBox;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView title;
    CheckBox checkbox;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MainListText);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MainListCheckBox);

    }
}
```

Checkbox

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/MainListCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/main_list_button_icon"/>
```

Checkbox Selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_list_uncheck"
    android:state_checked="false" />
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_list_check"
    android:state_checked="true"/>
```

[the button return 0 but 3 items were selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIBfN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution all i had to do was to make checkbox onClickListener inside MyViewHolder. I did that previously but it wasn't working for some reason.

```
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView title;
    CheckBox checkbox;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MainListText);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MainListCheckBox);
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkbox.isChecked()){
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
            }
        });

    }
}
```